# Add all variables of instances within class with the same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a class named `Robot`, which creates a number of instances of the classes `Segment` and `Pointmass`. All these instances have a variable `mass`. How can I obtain the total mass of all the objects within the object with the same variable name `mass`?

What I do right now:

```py
class Robot:
    def __init__(self, massJoint1, massJoint2, massJoint3, massSlide, reachSlide, massArm, lengthArm):
        self.joint1 = Pointmass(massJoint1)
        self.joint2 = Pointmass(massJoint2)
        self.joint3 = Pointmass(massJoint3)

        self.slide = Slide(massSlide, reachSlide)
        self.arm = Arm(massArm, lengthArm)

        self.totalmass = self.joint1.mass + self.joint2.mass + self.joint3.mass + self.slide.mass + self.arm.mass

    def printVars(self):
        attrs = vars(self)
        print(', \n'.join("%s: \t%s" % item for item in attrs.items()))
        print()


class Pointmass:
    def __init__(self, mass):
        self.mass = mass

        self.location = None


class Segment:
    def __init__(self, mass):
        self.mass = mass

        self.start = None
        self.end = None
```

In which

```py
self.totalmass = self.joint1.mass + self.joint2.mass + self.joint3.mass + self.slide.mass + self.arm.mass
```

is a very long line, and is really inconvenient when the `Robot` gains more arms and joints... Is there a better way to obtain the total mass?

Comment: Use a list, a `for` loop and `*args` ?

Comment: Seems like your `joint1`, `joint2`, `joint3` should be in a list.

Comment: If your robot is growing too many limbs, that's an indication that you should store them in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be storing the joints in separate attributes. Rather, store a simple `joints` list; then you can simply use `sum` with a generator expression.

```
self.totalmass = sum(j.mass for j in self.joints)
```

Comment: But in that case I would have to remember which joint is in which index of the list? I'd rather give them unique names,maybe I should't have used `jointx` in the example...

Comment: In that case you could use a dict and iterate through `self.joints.values()`; or, if you must, keep them as separate attributes but iterate through `[self.joint1, self.joint2]` etc.